# Why do I get two different status code from conn.getresponse().status in python?

Tags: python, http, url, https

so I want to check if a URL is reachable from python, and I got this code from googling:

```
def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return  resp.status < 400
```

Here is my URL: https://eurotableau.nomisonline.com.
It works fine if I just pass that in to the function. The resp.status is 302. However, if I add a port 443 at the end of it, https://eurotableau.nomisonline.com:443, it returns false. The resp.status is 400. I tried both URL in google Chrome, both of them work. So my question is why is this happening? Anyway I can include the port value and still get valid resp.status value (< 400)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http.client.HTTPSConnection` instead. The plain old `HTTPConnection` ignores the protocol that is part of the URL.

Comment: one more question, if the URL is http instead of https, will HTTPSConnection still work? Thanks.

Comment: You can do something like `Connection = HTTPSConnection if 'https' in p.netloc else HTTPConnection` and then use the class like before `conn = Connection(p.netloc)`. I don't have Python3 avaialble at the moment to check if `HTTPSConnection` works with non-SSL URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require the HEAD method but just wish to check if host is available then why not do:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

try:
    u = urlopen("https://eurotableau.nomisonline.com")
    u.close()
    print "Everything fine!"
except Exception, e:
    if hasattr(e, "code"):
        print "Server is there but something is wrong with rest of URL"
    else: print "Server is on vacations or was never there!"
    print e
```

This will establish a connection with server but it won't download any data unless you read it. It'll only read few KB to get the header (like when using HEAD method) and wait for you to request more. But you will close it there.

So, you can catch an exception and see what the problem is, or if there is no exception, just close the connection.

urllib2 will handle HTTPS and protocol://user@URL:PORT for you neatly.
 No worries about anything.

Comment: Its a great answer! But I'm wondering why does it take a good 3 seconds to run this code? I'm using python3.3 on macbook pro osx yosemite

Comment: Adding a timeout should help: u = urlopen("http://something.blah", timeout=0.5); I am wondering why using httplib directly doesn't give you same delay. It's just the time that OS requires to check all DNS entries from local to remote DNSs. In case when domain exists, then it is real TCP/IP timeout (socket waiting for TCP/IP handshake) and that can be controlled. But means if user has really slow connection (56K modem :D ) you might wrongly conclude that server is unavailable just because timeout expired.

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer just a little to cover all. And, hm, maybe you should modify your question title. It doesn't match your Q and even less my A. :D :D